# Does Mule support MySQL database connection pooling with XA transaction?

Tags: mysql, mule-component, mule-el, mule-cluster, mule-module-jpa

Does Mule support MySQL database connection pooling with XA transaction? if yes could you please provide me the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. You can configure it using Spring bean configuration like below.

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="mySqlXADataSource" name="MySqlXADataSource" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource">
        <spring:property name="user" value="root" />
        <spring:property name="password" value="root" />
        <spring:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dev" />
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
```

and refer the above bean definition in mule mysql connector like

```
<db:mysql-config name="MySQL_XA_Configuration" dataSource-ref="mySqlXADataSource" doc:name="MySQL Configuration" />
```

For your reference [here is an example flow on XA transaction between MySQL and JMS ActiveMQ](https://github.com/ram-bavireddi/mule-examples/blob/master/multi-resource-transaction/src/main/app/jboss-xa-transaction.xml)

Comment: Above Data source supports XA transaction .But how to implement connection pooling for the same Datasource? How to configure the properties like minPoolSize,maxPoolSize like that !!!

Answer (score 0):

Mule does support XA Transaction handling. Here's a good example with configurations.

http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/how-to-work-with-jdbc-and-xa-transactions/

Remember that Mule supports the transaction handling but the real work is the XML configuration of the Spring Beans (Java).